# RaycastHit.point always returns (0,0,0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am just getting started with unity, and I tried following along with a couple of tutorials. That all went well, and I was learning fine, until I tried to learn a little about navmesh agents. I watched Brackeys' video on it and copied his code exactly, but it doesn't work for me. After debugging, I figured out that the hit.point always returns (0,0,0) Can someone help me with this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cam;

    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering it a little late, but maybe other people will benefit.
If your hit.point is (0, 0, 0), something close to it (0, 0, 0.0003) or very far away (0, 0, -5491), then it's possible that it didn't hit any collider at all. Before using hit.point value you should always check if it hit something.
Do so with `if(hit.collider != null)`.

Comment: Surely `Physics.Raycast` would return false if no collider was hit?